# How to remove "Recent apps" when pressing Home?

Tags: applications, samsung, home-screen, home-button

When pressing "Home" button on my Samsung Galaxy Core Plus (Android 4.2.2, *not rooted*), I always get this "Recent apps" view, which I don't want.

**How to have the real home instead (i.e. desktop with icons) ?**

[image]

Comment: Your Android version?

Comment: Android 4.2.2 @Firelord

Comment: On TouchWiz, the Samsung Launcher, this view comes up if you hard-press Home (i.e. press-and-hold). It goes to the home page if you click the button. I couldn't find a setting where this is reversed or configurable. I have proven this on my three (3) Samsung devices, and it works identically. Investigate your click duration when doing this action.

Comment: @wbogacz can I disable TouchWiz on my non-rooted Samsung device? and get standard Android behaviour?

Comment: You can certainly install a different launcher, leading to your being able to disable TouchWiz. I think this is a dramatic move to evade the short practice involved in learning short vs. long clicking to satisfaction. Adding a different launcher, of course, leads to different techniques to be learned, anyway.

Comment: Ok @wbogacz I'll check if this comes from my button click duration to see if I can solve it easily :)